# How to affect the listview when a horizontal scroll view inside that list view gets scrolled

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a list view and in each list item there is a horizontal scroll view.
If I scroll a scroll view of an item then it should affect scroll view belongs to all other items in that list view.

Workaround I tried :

```
mViewHolder.mHorizontalScrollView
                    .setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            selectedItemIndex = mViewHolder.index;
                            SCROLL_X = v.getScrollX();
                            SCROLL_Y = v.getScrollY();
                             mListView.invalidateViews();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
            mViewHolder.mHorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(SCROLL_X, SCROLL_Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

What u are trying to do is a a grid. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground)
its a recyclerview with a *CustomLayoutManager* this will probably do what u want. btw: recycler is the way to go not listviews any more.

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know how it works on my requirement !

Comment: Download the sample and take a look if that is what u want before implementing becuase that could and will take a while.